# Reload page from server when click back button from browser

Tags: html, http

I develop web shop and have a problem. When user buy item, i save it in session and change basket badge. Next, if user click back button, page take content from cache and basket badge would be empty.
Is it possible to force page to load from server, when user click back button in browser and not take content from cache?

Comment: No code? Haven't indicated what language you're using and hard to help without knowing what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

i understand your question and the answer has nothing to do with server code.
The onload event should be fired when the user hits the back button. Elements not created via JavaScript will retain their values. I suggest keeping a backup of the data used in dynamically created element within an INPUT TYPE="hidden" or TEXTAREA set to display:none then onload using the value of the textbox to rebuild the dynamic elements to the way they were.
HTML:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="refreshed" value="no"/>
```

Javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

```js
  onload = function () {
                   var e = document.getElementById("refreshed");
                   if (e.value == "no") e.value = "yes";
                   else { e.value = "no"; location.reload(); }
               }
```

```html
</script>
```

i hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
  onload = function () {
                   var e = document.getElementById("refreshed");
                   if (e.value == "no") e.value = "yes";
                   else { e.value = "no"; location.reload(); }
               }
```